# Pros and cons of WordPress vs. own PHP Framework

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system, blogs

I have a website build in own php framework, complete with an elaborate product catalogue and cms system. Now I would like to add a blog and I wanted others' opinions on whether to keep using the framework and develop it as fully integrated with existing website and cms or if I should use wordpress. I am leaning towards the first option but was wondering if I'm not missing something important about wordpress that should sway me.

I have never used wordpress before so will have to learn it first to customise it fully to my requirements (will be creating custom template). I know it's a great blogging tool for people not that into code, but I'm wondering that if you do know coding, if it's still the best option.

Opinions, pros and cons will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why you would want to develop your own PHP blog, but also several reasons why you should use an existing framework like Wordpress.

Developing your own:

- Better understanding of how things work, making it easier to customize it.
- The blog is fully yours, no license applies.

Using Wordpress:

- A lot easier to create blog post
- You can easily install themes etc. to customize your blog.

All in all, I would recommend Wordpress, but thats just my opinion.

Go with whatever suits your needs :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me a bit more about the learning curve of going with Wordpress? How long do you think it would take me to set it up, complete with my own custom template? Also, would it allow me to customise it fully with my existing website (e.g. linking certain product categories and products with certain blog posts?)

Comment: Well without going too much into details..
Wordpress is extremely easy to set up, and also offers a lot of documentation on how to customize it. When it comes to integrating it with your website this will also very easy and possible (if you know html and css). Keep in mind that the whole blog is contained within a separate folder on your webserver. So to integrate it you would need to add a link from your current website to the blog, and then add a link back to the website.

Personally, I prefer to keep the blog and the website separated, but this is entirely up to you.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful. I think I'll go with Wordpress.